# Multiplying columns in separate pandas dataframes

Tags: python, pandas, multiplication

I'm trying to multiply data from 2 different dataframes and my code as below:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

df1 = pd.DataFrame({'v_contract_number': ['VN120001438','VN120001439',
                                          'VN120001440','VN120001438',
                                          'VN120001439','VN120001440'],
                                            'Currency': ['VND','USD','KRW','USD','KRW','USD'],
                                        'Amount': [10000,5000,6000,200,150,175]})
df2 = pd.DataFrame({'Currency': ['VND','USD','KRW'],'Rate': [1,23000,1200]})
print(df1)

# df1
  v_contract_number Currency  Amount
0       VN120001438      VND   10000
1       VN120001439      USD    5000
2       VN120001440      KRW    6000
3       VN120001438      USD     200
4       VN120001439      KRW     150
5       VN120001440      USD     175

print(df2)
  Currency   Rate
0      VND      1
1      USD  23000
2      KRW   1200

df1 = df1.merge(df2)
df1['VND AMount'] = df1['Amount'].mul(df1['Rate'])
df1.drop('Rate', axis=1, inplace=True)
print(df1)

# result
  v_contract_number Currency  Amount  VND AMount
0       VN120001438      VND   10000       10000
1       VN120001439      USD    5000   115000000
2       VN120001438      USD     200     4600000
3       VN120001440      USD     175     4025000
4       VN120001440      KRW    6000     7200000
5       VN120001439      KRW     150      180000
```

This is exactly what I want but I would like to know that have another way to not merge and drop as I did?
The reason that I drop ‘Rate’ because I dont want it appears in my report.

Thanks and best regards

Comment: If you want to avoid `.drop` you can do `df1["Amount"] *= df1[["Currency"]].merge(df2, on="Currency", how="left")["Rate"]`

Comment: @AndrejKesely Thank you so much, but what I want is add new colums name VND Amount and calculate it based on Amount, Currency and Rate. If use your code, it will multiply directly to Amount.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use pandas' map for this:

```
df2 = df2.set_index('Currency').squeeze() # squeeze converts to a Series

df1.assign(VND_Amount = df1.Amount.mul(df1.Currency.map(df2)))

  v_contract_number Currency  Amount  VND_Amount
0       VN120001438      VND   10000       10000
1       VN120001439      USD    5000   115000000
2       VN120001440      KRW    6000     7200000
3       VN120001438      USD     200     4600000
4       VN120001439      KRW     150      180000
5       VN120001440      USD     175     4025000
```

Answer (score 1):

You can avoid the drop by not overwriting `df1` on the merge operation:

```
df1["VND Amount"] = df1.merge(df2, on="Currency").eval("Amount * Rate")
```

Alternatively you can use `.reindex` to align df2 to df1 based on the currency column:

```
df1["VND Amount"] = (
    df1["Amount"] * 
    (df2.set_index("Currency")["Rate"]  # set the index and return Rate column
        .reindex(df1["Currency"])       # align "Rate" values to df1 "Currency"
        .to_numpy()                     # get numpy array to avoid pandas 
                                        #   auto alignment on math ops
    )
)
```